# module not found but it's in packages list

Tags: python, import, module, anaconda, package

(Python 3.9.12) Using the Anaconda prompt, the command `conda list` displays a listing of installed packages including pyqt, qt, and qtpy.

Using the Spyder console, both `import pyqt` and `import qt` throw the error **No module named** *[that]* .

But `import qtpy` works.

Searches on this issue have turned up the possibility of the environment being set incorrectly. I experimented with that but was unable to figure out what that means or how it affects the problem.  Many of the issues found were too specific to other variables (pip vs conda, or package relationships) to be helpful.

**Situation update:**
I had been trying to install the new module from a local (network drive) repository using `conda install --offline` and couldn't get it to work.  I had tried using the pathname/file name as an argument as well as changing the Python working directory to the repository folder first (to shorten the pathname) but neither worked.

Then I copied the package folder to a directory in the same branch as the Anaconda installation and repeated the two methods with no better luck; the install attempts failed and it wouldn't import, even though a version of it appeared in the conda packages list.

Then I appended the packages folder containing the folders copied from the local repository to the sys.path list and now pyqt6 will import!  Success??

- The conda packages list still shows only `pyqt`; not `pyqt5` or `pyqt6`.
- There is a folder in the Lib/site-packages folder named PyQt5.  The folder I added to sys.path is PyQt6.

Neither `import pyqt` or `import pyqt5` work, but `import pyqt6` does.  I haven't tried to use it in a program, yet, but the import worked in the console.

**Remaining questions:**

- Why can't I import modules in the packages list?
- Why doesn't the package list match the folders in the site-packages list?
- Is PyQt6 installed?  The contents of the Lib/site-packages/PyQt5 folder is not the same as the PyQt6 folder copied from the local repository, so just copying the folder to the site-packages folder is probably a bad idea.
- If it's not properly installed, how is that done?  This may be a new issue but I've searched this site for several hours and haven't found a method that works.
- If adding the copied-packages folder to the sys.path is workable, should that be built into the system path list?  It seems like it would be better to figure out how to properly install it.

Comment: Show us the output of this code inside spyder: `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: ['C:\\RTN\\Anaconda3\\python39.zip', 'C:\\RTN\\Anaconda3\\DLLs', 'C:\\RTN\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\RTN\\Anaconda3', '', 'C:\\RTN\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\RTN\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\RTN\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\RTN\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']